# SpriteKit: How to implement touchesBegan and touchesEnded to split action into two parts?

Tags: ios, game-physics

I'm trying to do a little archery game and at the moment I have a basic `touchesBegan` method that uses `SKActions` to animate an archer and shoot an arrow.

I'm having a hard time getting it so that I hold touch to draw the bow, then when I release, the rest of the animation plays out and the arrow shoots.

I tried it with using two separate `NSMutableArray` Atlases spread across `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` methods with `userInteractionEnabled` flags but that was a bit of a no-go...

Ultimately I want the duration of the hold to dictate a value for `applyImpulse:CGVectorMake`.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
SKNode *archerNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"archerNode"];

if (archerNode != nil)
 {
    SKAction *draw = [SKAction animateWithTextures:self.archerDraw timePerFrame:0.075];
    [archerNode runAction:draw];

    SKAction *shootArrow = [SKAction runBlock:^{

        SKNode *arrowNode = [self createArrowNode];

        [self addChild:arrowNode];
        [arrowNode.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(20.0, 0)];
    }];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[draw, shootArrow]];

    [archerNode runAction:sequence];
   }
  }
```

Comment: Please post the complete code related to this question from the touch delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiate the charging animation in the `touchesBegan:` section & move the arrow release code in the `touchesEnded:` (+ `touchesCancelled:`) function. Keeping the time at which the touches began in an instance variable will help you calculate the impulse vector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems now that it will play the full animation regardless of how long I hold down the touch, however I am able to hold off on releasing an arrow if I'm still touching. I'm guessing I have to implement a timer or something. I'm able to fire off arrows like a machine gun too by just clicking which somewhat kills the illusion...

Comment: That's what my last sentence was about.

Comment: Ah OK, so I can use the same touchesBegan instance variable I'll be using to calculate impulse vector to control whether the animation draws at all?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is great! I managed to get the time difference and it's starting to take shape beautifully! :D